# Restricted singular values of random matrix

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ be a large square matrix, consisting of i.i.d. Gaussian entries. Then it is known that the singular values of $X$ follow the Marchenko-Pastur law.

Now let's introduce an adversary, who arbitrarily selects $p/2$ rows of X and form a submatrix. Can the adversary succeed to make the singular values of this matrix look very different from the Marchenko-Pastur law of a $\frac{p}{2} \times p$ Gaussian matrix?

Comment: This might be of some interest: http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.5969

Comment: It is not the spectrum of X that follows the MP law, but rather the singular values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what do you mean by "look very different". I assume that you mean 
that the empirical measure is close to that of the MP law. The answer below 
assumes this is what you meant.

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: there is an exponential (in $p$) number of ways to choose the rows. But the
concentration of the empirical measure is exponential in $p^2$.

Comment: Could you please name some references? Thanks!

Comment: For the concentration a handy reference is my paper with A. Guionnet ECP 2000.